# Split string with colon (:) and separate the numbers with colon

Tags: c#, regex

Hello i had a problem on separating a string.
Below are the sample string.

Input - D93:E93 E98 E9:E10 E26 D76:E76 D83:E83 D121:D124

Output - D93, E93, E98, E9, E10, E26, D76, E76, D83, E83, D121, D122, D123, D124

If you separate the two with the same letter it continues counting.
Please help me..

Regards,

Comment: Do you have more info as in sample code? What is it you are doing exactly, your question is about splitting but then you say something about continues counting? What is it you are really after and what have you tried.

Comment: What do you mean "it continues counting"?

Comment: It continues if they have the same letter. the example is D121:D124 when you separate it the output will be D121, D122, D123, D124 until it ends in D124.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
var input = "D93:E93 E98 E9:E10 E26 D76:E76 D83:E83 D121:D124";
var list = input.Split(' ');

var result = new List<String>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    var parts = item.Split(':');
    if (parts.Length == 1) result.Add(parts[0]);
    else
    {
        if (parts[0].Substring(0, 1).CompareTo(parts[1].Substring(0, 1)) == 0)
        {
            var i = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0].Substring(1));
            var j = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1].Substring(1));

            while (i < j)
            {
                result.Add(parts[0].Substring(0, 1) + i);
                i++;
            }

            if (i == j)
            {
                result.Add(parts[0].Substring(0, 1) + i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(parts[0]);
            result.Add(parts[1]);
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));

//output
D93, E93, E98, E9, E10, E26, D76, E76, D83, E83, D121, D122, D123, D124
```

Comment: It continues if they have the same letter. the example is D121:D124 when you separate it the output will be D121, D122, D123, D124 until it ends in D124

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use a combination of `String.Split()` and `String.Join()`:

```
var result = String.Join(", ", s.Split(':', ' '));
```

Comment: It continues if they have the same letter. the example is D121:D124 when you separate it the output will be D121, D122, D123, D124 until it ends in D124

Answer (score 2):

Try string.Split

```
string input = "D93:E93 E98 E9:E10 E26 D76:E76 D83:E83 D121:D124";
var output = input.Split(new [] {':', ' '});
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

or if you need the commas:

```
string input = "D93:E93 E98 E9:E10 E26 D76:E76 D83:E83 D121:D124";
var output = input.Split(new [] {':', ' '});
var outstr = output.Aggregate((a,e) => a + ", " + e);
Console.WriteLine(outstr);
```

Comment: It continues if they have the same letter. the example is D121:D124 when you separate it the output will be D121, D122, D123, D124 until it ends in D124